# Removing space at the top left and right of div

Tags: html, css

I am starting to work with css and have basic issue.

I have a div element:

```css
.top {
  background-color: #3B5998;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="top">...</div>
```

The colour code is taking effect (good).

The problem I have is that there seems to be a bit of **white space on left, top and right of the div**. How do I get rid of the white space? For example if you take a look at Facebook page, the top part is completely blue, there is no white space at the top.

Comment: Although there may be a specific answer to this question, you should look into using a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to reset both the default **padding** and **margin** attributes in your stylesheet:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As @Jason McCreary mentions, you should also look into using a reset stylesheet. The one he links to, Eric Meyer's CSS reset, is a great place to start.

It also looks like you're missing a semi-colon in your css, it should look as follows:

```
.top
{
    background-color:#3B5998;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Oh god.. I had gone mad on this one... I finished 3 tutorials on CSS and none of them mentioned that the body itself has a margin/padding :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the same issue when starting out; but if you plan to make websites that are cross browser compatible I recommend using a css reset stylesheet;

essentially they reset the styles that browser add to elements (which can be different for different browsers).

Just my 2 cents on this kind of thing. a quick google for css reset will give a number of options.

Answer (score 4):

There's `padding` on the `<body>` of the page. You can fix this like so:

```
body
{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the change, same issue.

Comment: Try *{margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem . just try this :

```
html, body {
    margin-top:-13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need some padding inside the div, you should choose padding:

```
padding:top right bottom left;
```

example:

```
padding:5px; /* 5px padding at all sides)*/
padding:5px 3px; /* top & bottom 5px padding but right left 3px padding) */
padding:5px 3px 4px; /* top 5px, bottom 4px padding but left right 3px) */
padding:1px 2px 3px 4px; /* top 1px, right 2px bottom 3px & left 4px) */
```

Similarly to control the space outside the div, you can use margin.

Margin will use exact same formula.

Answer (score 1):

After long time I found the correct solution for me:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

We need define the overflow in the horizontal.

Comment: That's bad. You can never scroll horizontally!

Answer (score 1):

If other answers don't work, try `position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;` or `display:flex`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked for me:

```
body {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px !important;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue i had lately also, but even though i used padding:0px even added the !important on body didn't solved it... the actual problem was its position ... which you can do by using background-position:50% 50%; or by automatically let it choose the center position of the screen .. which is margin:0 auto; or margin:auto; that solved it for me ... hope for you all also. i realized the margin is what was needed after i tried @HAS's response thanks man ur awesome ... sorry for zombify the post

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0px; would remove all spaces around the element.

padding: 0px; clears the area around the content

you can try:

```
html, body {margin: 0px; padding:0px;}
body {margin: auto;}
```

with margin:auto; the browser calculates a margin.

You can also use

```
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

this will remove all default margins and spaces. But be careful while using:

```
position: absolute;
```

The 'position' property can take 4 values, static, relative, fixed and absolute. Then you can use top, bottom, left, right properties to position your element. This depends on your layout. This link might be useful https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: Please include a short description of how or why this works.

Comment: I don't have super powers (and I didn't downvote), but I believe the question is much better now.