# CSS - How to remove white <div> margins

Tags: html, css, image

I've placed a picture on my html page but it lefts some white margins at the top and on both sides. How do I remove those? I've tried setting  margins to zero.

```css
body div:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url('/resources/picture.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your body has some margins.

Try adding this css -

```
body, img{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Why have you targeted the `img`?

Comment: Worked with margin:0, thanks!

P.S: Didn't have to target img also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` or Meyer CSS Reset

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset both the margin and padding

```
body div:nth-child(1){
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6619637