# Why do I get an offset on div's left with "width: 100%" property?

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, offset

I was simply trying to programming a bottom banner `<div>` and I was getting the desired results, except for one strange offset (that I didn't set) on the left of the `<div>` tag.

Below the code-snippet with the issue:

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(50deg, #97f8a9, #f7d69c);
}

.under_banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    top: 80%;
    border-top: 3px solid #ff5555;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #f6d808, #ffc107 10%);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.problem {
    color: #990099;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="under_banner">
    <p>Sample banner example with <span class="problem">strange horizontal offset</span> - Hello Stackoverflow community!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

With a minimum of CSS-position knowledge, I fixed it putting `left: 0` property on `.underbanner` div class, like shown in this other snippet:

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(50deg, #97f8a9, #f7d69c);
}

.under_banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    top: 80%;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid #ff5555;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #f6d808, #ffc107 10%);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.problem {
    color: #009900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="under_banner">
    <p>Sample banner example with <span class="problem">fixed horizontal offset</span> - Hello Stackoverflow community!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

So, my question is substantially theoric: why do I get an horizontal offset on the left with `width: 100%` property on `.under_banner`? Maybe has the `<div>` element got an hidden offset that triggers for some reason I don't know? And also, is `left: 0` property the best solution to fix this issue?

Comment: By default, `body` has some `margin` on it. Try to assign `margin: 0` to the `body`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing space at the top left and right of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619555/removing-space-at-the-top-left-and-right-of-div)

Comment: @Hao Wu yeah, it works. Now I'd like to know if the best solution is the one you advised me or  the one I found. I believe yours is better because the solution will be applied on every element inside the body instead of create exceptions on every element, didn't it?

Comment: Technically, yes. Setting `margin` and `padding` to `0` for both `html` and `body` is just to make sure it works for every browser. But since nowadays almost every mainstream browser having the same standards, so you don't have to do that anymore.